# Prestashop 1.6 Advanced Stock management : negative stock

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6, stock

i'm currently working on a PS 1.6 shop which uses advanced stock management.

Here is the issue we're in trouble with :

- an order has 1 product (let's say with 1 quantity) which has **negative stock** (real quantity)
- when this order is shipped, the product stock (let's say **-10**) goes from +1 instead of -1 (in this case **from -10 to -9 instead of -11**)...

I've tried several ways to correct like

```
 if(StockAvailable::dependsOnStock($product['id_product'], (int)$order->id_shop)) {
            StockAvailable::updateQuantity($product['product_id'], $product['product_attribute_id'], (int)$product['product_quantity'], $order->id_shop);
        }
```

but nothing changed... In ps_stock_available, quantity is not good (and I don't want to correct it by a simple SQL request which could have massive side effects)

Has someone ever experienced this ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Can't help you on this but keep in mind that v1.6 advanced stock management feature had been massively flawed with many unsolved bugs... That's why it had been removed in PS 1.7

Comment: Yes, I'm totally aware of this removal, I'm also working on PS 1.7... unfortunately, in this case our customer still wants to use Advanced Stock Management ^^ so i've to handle this